# How to print spaces between values in loop?

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

How to put spaces between values in a print() statement
for example:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, sep='', end='')
```

prints

```
012345
```

I would like it to print

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Then why are you using `sep=''`?

Comment: remove the `sep=''` and try it again.

Comment: The loop isn't needed either: `print(*range(5), end='')`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Shouldn't that be sep instead of end if they are all in one print?

Comment: look I have tried but it is giving the same result, I want it to put double space between the numbers, they so joined
I want something like 1 2 3 not 123

Comment: @grieve: That just suppresses the newline, which behaves like his code.

Answer (score 6):

While others have given an answer, a good option here is to avoid using a loop and multiple print statements at all, and simply use the `*` operator to [unpack your iterable into the arguments](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for print:

```
>>> print(*range(5))
0 1 2 3 4
```

As `print()` adds spaces between arguments automatically, this makes for a really concise and readable way to do this, without a loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...    print(i, end=' ')
...
0 1 2 3 4
```

Explanation: the `sep` parameter only affects the seperation of *multiple* values in *one* `print` statement. But here, you have *multiple* print statements with *one value each*, so you have to specify `end` to be a space (per default it's newline).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the space between quotes after the end. It should be:

```
end = " "
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, you could also do

```
for i in range(5):
    print i,
```

or

```
print " ".join(["%s"%i for i in range(5)])
```